# Granting sudo access without prompting for password

Tags: sudo

I have added a username to the sudoer file, but as you can see below, when I run `sudo ls` I have to enter the password. How can I fix that in order to run passwordless sudo commands for the `test` user.

```
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for test:
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
test    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
test@ubuntu:~$
```

UPDATE:

After setting `NOPASSWD:`, still I have to enter the password. See below:

```
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for test:
test@ubuntu:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
test    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
test@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` for giving user `test` access without password

Note that if `test` user is in `admin` or `sudo` group, it's settings would be overridden in groups settings. To avoid that, write your user settings after group settings:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
...
test    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Is test user in admin or sudo group ? @mahmood

Comment: I've updated my answer @mahmood

Comment: OK I found that `%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` fixes the problem. Thanks for th hints.